# How do you properly "snap" to a value?

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-accuracy

Let say I've set a step of 0.1 in my application.
So, whatever fp value I get, I just need 1 digit after the comma.

So, `47.93434` must be `47.9` (or at least, the nearest fp representable value).

If I write this:

```
double value = 47.9;
```

It correctly "snap" to the nearest fp value it can get, which is:

```
47.89999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375 // fp value
101111.11100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011 // binary
```

Now, suppose "I don't write those values", but I got them from a software.
And than I need to snap it. I wrote this function:

```
inline double SnapValue(double value, double step) {
    return round(value / step) * step;
}
```

But it returns these values:

```
47.900000000000005684341886080801486968994140625 // fp value
101111.11100110011001100110011001100110011001100110100 // binary
```

which is formally a little far than the first example (its the "next" fp value, `011 + 1`).

How would you get the first value (which is "more correct") for each input value?

[Here's](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ca1dd02b14fdbaf) the testing code.

**NOTE**: the step can be different - i.e. `step = 0.25` need to snap value around the nearest 0.25 X. Example: a step of `0.25` will return values as `0`, `0.25`, `0.50`, `0.75`, `1.0`, `1.25` and so on. Thus, given an input of `1.30`, it need to wrap to the nearest snapped value - i.e. `1.25`.

Comment: out of curiosity: why not integers and interpret them as multiples of `0.1` ?

Comment: @user463035818; because I'm in a system where integer representation would be too much bigger, such as step increment with different tempo/bpm/rates. Also, I like to process FP for take advantage of SIMD (which should be faster than integer calculation, in some cases).

Comment: Here's your problem, you're using float or double which **cannot** store some values. Your example proves as much. You have to use either fixed point or something of the like as @user463035818 said.

Comment: @Trinopoty: the approx I have above is almost ok for me. My concern is how to select the "nearest" value, that's all.

Comment: `479 * 0.1 != 479 / 10` because `0.1` is itself imprecise. Your `step` is not exactly one tenth. The resulting value is indeed nearest to a multiple of `step` - it's just not nearest to a multiple of one tenth.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I see. So what the way to always snap to the nearest snapping value using a function?

Comment: Define "snapping value".

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: the nearest "snapped" value I can pick (i.e. `47.89999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375`, not `47.900000000000005684341886080801486968994140625`)

Comment: What's *"snapped" value*? If you can provide a precise mathematical definition, then you'd probably have your answer. That said, if you pass `10` to `SnapValue` instead of `0.1`, and adjust the math accordingly, you will get the result you expect for this specific example.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: yes, but if you pass 0.25 (as specified in the edited question) it won't work.

Comment: [1.3 does get correctly snapped to 1.25](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45497e643335c258) by your code. That's more or less a coincidence - `0.25` is precisely representable as a finite binary fraction, while `0.1` is not.

Comment: @markzzz: It works fine, if you convert the code correctly.  When NathanOliver's correct answer (now deleted) changed from 0.1 to 10.0, that was not "multiply by 100", it was a reciprocal.  Your conversion of "0.25" to "step = 25" failed for obvious reasons, but "step = 4" would have worked fine.  Your snap size should probably be represented as a ratio of two integers in the end, to give you more flexibility.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I see! Somethings like this? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b445768b6a3b760c

Comment: @markzzz: Like that, but you should have a `round()` call when finding the reciprocal also.

Comment: @BenVoigt do you mean `int stepRec = round(1 / step);` :O Isn't already guaranteed by the cast to int?

Comment: A cast to `int` truncates towards zero. If `1/step` happens to be a hair below `10.0`, casting to `int` would produce `9`

Comment: Also, if `step` is ever not of the form `1/N`, you are going to have a bad time. Personally, I'd pass `N` to being with - that would make it clear to the caller what the function can and cannot do.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik right for the "int" ;) thanks. About "step not in the form 1/n" what do you mean? Example?

Comment: @markzzz: A step like 0.4 would not be in the form 1/n. It is 2/5. You need integer numerator and denominator to get any useful ratio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use rational values instead of floating point. The latter are often inaccurate already, so not really an ideal match for a step.

```
inline double snap(double original, int numerator, int denominator)
{
    return round(original * denominator / numerator) * numerator / denominator;
}
```

Say you want steps of 0.4, then use 2 / 5:

```
snap(1.7435, 2, 5) = round(4.35875) * 2 / 5 = 4 * 2 / 5 = 1.6 (or what comes closest to it)
```

Comment: I see your point. But what if I don't have `denominator` and `numerator` but only the `step` in floating point?

Comment: Then use a proper routine to turn a float into a rational. But since you define the step, it is better to define it as num and denom.